# Where can I find a publicly hosted image that is replaced with a new image each day but maintains the same URL?

Tags: internet, images

This is a weird question, but I'm using a "dashboard" app that in addition to showing me really useful information, allows me to display an image or gif by supplying a URL. It is meant to display a company's logo or something, but I just want it to show an interesting image that changes every day. Does anyone know of a publicly hosted image that is replaced with a new image each day but maintains the same URL?

For example, if xkcd's comic of the day (http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/ozymandias.png) were always located at today.png instead of changing based on the name of the comic (ozymandias.png), it would be perfect! I searched all over google and couldn't find such a thing. Sorry if I wasted your time with this question.

Comment: any webcam site should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A satelite image would be a useful thing to add (given that you have the space). Try something like [this link](http://www.intelliweather.net/imagery/IntelliWeather/sat_nat_640x480.jpg).

Comment: This is a great answer and so is @meuh's. I ended up using a live-updating weather cam which you can find here: http://weather.weatherbug.com/NY/New%20York-weather/weather-cams/local-cams.html